# Is it possible to sign an application and upload it to the App Store with Wildcard in house certificate?

Tags: upload, app-store, certificate, wildcard, provisioning

I just submitted a update for an old app and I think I used a wildcard in house distribution cert. Apple confirmed to me that the app is ok and the update is already in the App Store. I'm concerned because that cert is going to expired soon and I'm afraid that my app is not going to work after that in the AppStore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the app is approved, and you renew your developer enrollment on time, it no longer matters if the certificate or provision used to submit the app expires.  The app will keep working for any customer who downloads or buys it from the iTunes App store, essentially forever.